# TypeError: options.xhr is not a function

Tags: javascript

I try using javascript FormData and ajax asynchronous upload,but there is a problem around me.It say "TypeError: options.xhr is not a function",In jQuery API have this parameter has.this my code:

```
The ${basePath} is jsp/java project web path.
```

```js
var basePath = "${basePath}";
window.onload=function(){
  var i_file = document.getElementById("file");

  var submit_Btn = document.getElementById("submit");
  submit_Btn.addEventListener("click",fileUpload,false);
}

var fileUpload = {
  getTarget : function(target){
    return this.fileTarget = target || document.getElementById("file");
  },
  getXHR : function(){
    var xhr;
    try {
      xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e) {
      var IEXHRVers =["Msxml3.XMLHTTP","Msxml2.XMLHTTP","Microsoft.XMLHTTP"];
      for (var i=0,len=IEXHRVers.length;i< len;i++) {
        try {
          xhr = new ActiveXObject(IEXHRVers[i]);
        }
        catch(e) {
          continue;
        }
      }
    }
    return xhr;
  },
  handleEvent : function(e){
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]);
    var xhr_provide = this.getXHR();    
    xhr_provide.upload.addEventListener("progress",updateProgress,false);
    $.ajax(basePath + "FileUploadServlet",{
      data:formData,
      processData:false,
      type:"post",
      xhr:xhr_provide,
      success:function(data,status){
        //alert("ok")
      },
      error:function(error){
        console.info(error);//there will throws error obj
      },
      contentType: false
    });

  }
}
var updateProgress = function(e){
  console.info(Math.round((e.position/e.total)*100));
}
```

```html
<form action="${basePath }FileUploadServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="提交"/>
</form>
```

main code as above.

Comment: The `xhr` property should be a *function* which returns an `XMLHttpRequest` instance, not an `XMLHttpRequest` variable. `var xhr_provide = this.getXHR;` without executing it should work

Comment: yes,you are right. but ,I need bind "progress" event ,implement progress bar function,What should I do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using jQuery, here's code I know works - it adds progress event to jQuery's ajax family of functions, it's used every day on company website

```
(function ($) {
    var originalXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr;
    $.ajaxSetup({
        progress: function () { },
        upprogress: function () { },
        xhr: function () {
            var req = originalXhr();
            if (req) {
                if (typeof req.addEventListener === "function") {
                    req.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                        this.progress(evt);
                    } .bind(this), false);
                }
                if (req.upload && typeof req.upload.addEventListener === "function") {
                    req.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                        this.upprogress(evt);
                    } .bind(this), false);
                }
            }
            return req;
        }
    });
    return true;
    /* usage:
    * $.ajax({
    *     url: "./json.js",
    *     type: "GET",
    *     dataType: "json",
    *     progress: function (evt) {
    *         if (evt.lengthComputable) {
    *             console.log("Loaded " + parseInt((evt.loaded / evt.totalSize * 100), 10) + "%");
    *         }
    *         else {
    *             console.log("Length not computable.");
    *         }
    *     }
    * }); 
    * $.ajax({
    *     url: "./json.js",
    *     type: "POST",
    *     dataType: "json",
    *     upprogress: function (evt) {
    *         if (evt.lengthComputable) {
    *             console.log("Loaded " + parseInt((evt.loaded / evt.totalSize * 100), 10) + "%");
    *         }
    *         else {
    *             console.log("Length not computable.");
    *         }
    *     }
    * }); 
    */
})(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my questions.I refer to the above code,this code seem can solve the problem,but why!It just trigger  "load" function,"progress" no trigger.

Comment: it **adds** progress event to jQueery's ajax family of functions

Comment: Was finally I found,"req.addEventListener...." modify to "req.upload.addEventListener"

Comment: I see the bug in my code :p it's a download progress, not an upload progress

Comment: updated the code for separate upload/download progress events